# python for x in y loop does not complete

Tags: python, for-loop

trying to make a script that extracts song information from a playlist.

This is the beginning of my playlist:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:402,Junior's Eyes - Black Sabbath
/Users/omitted/Black Sabbath/[1978] Never Say Die!/03. Junior's Eyes.mp3
#EXTINF:327,After Forever - Black Sabbath
/Users/omitted/Black Sabbath/[1971] Master of Reality/02. After Forever.mp3
#EXTINF:341,Killing Yourself to Live - Black Sabbath
/Users/omitted/Black Sabbath/[1973] Sabbath Bloody Sabbath/05. Killing Yourself to Live.mp3
#EXTINF:210,Rock 'n' Roll Doctor - Black Sabbath
/Users/omitted/Black Sabbath/[1976] Technical Ecstasy/06. Rock 'n' Roll Doctor.mp3
```

And this is the script i wrote:

```
import re

f = open('Sabbath.m3u', 'r')
pTitle = re.compile('(?<=,)[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9 \']+[A-Za-z0-9]')
pArtist = re.compile('(?<=- )[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9 ]+[A-Za-z0-9]')

for str in f:
  title = pTitle.search(str)
  artist = pArtist.search(str)
  print artist.group() + ' - ' + title.group()

f.close()
```

The result of running the script is:

> Black Sabbath - Junior's Eyes

and that's it. Why doesn't it loop through the entire file? It clearly gets to the line #2 since line #1 is '#EXTM3U' in every .m3u file.

Keep in mind, please, I want to know why this doesn't work, not just the replacement code that'll do the trick.

Comment: I think your regex is wrong, cant reproduce it, the regex doesnt find anything AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: Is this really the code you're using? As lapinkoira pointed out, this code crashes. It shouldn't even print anything because it crashes when reading the very first line of the file.

Comment: A single regex to extract all fields in one go is probably going to be both more robust and easier to code.

Comment: I am having difficulties with python's regex, I think it's unnecessary complex. In SQL, for example, I'd use `regexp_replace(str, '$EXTINF:\d{3,4},([\w ]+?) - ([\w ]+?)$', '\1')` to access the title and '\2' as the third argument to extract the band, but could't find the same option in python.

Answer (score 2):

There are some lines in your file where the regex fails to match. In that case, the Match object is `None`, and `None` doesn't have a `.group()` property, causing a `AttributeError` to be raised. You should be seeing that error in your console.

You could do something like

```
for line in f:
  t = pTitle.search(line)
  title = t.group() if t else "(N.A.)" 
  a = pArtist.search(line) 
  artist = a.group() if a else "(N.A.)" 
  print '{} - {}'.format(artist, title)
```

Comment: `title = t.group() or "(N.A.)"` would still fail if `t` is `None`. Another way to approach this will be to use `if all([title, artist]):`  before trying to access their `.group()` method.

Comment: this too is returning the same output as above. i am running python as a shell command `python script2.py`